# Facebook Open Graph cannot pull the featured image properly in Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, metadata, sharing

I have several wordpress websites.

But in one of those sites,
Facebook Open Graph doesn't seem to pull the featured image properly.

So I tested the urls in Facebook Object Debugger :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Then it showed me this kind of error :

> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Meta Tags In Body: Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be > > because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
>   Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

And this kind of warning :

> Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> og:image should be larger: Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://maummeditationbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/635764_thumb-221x130.jpg' will be used instead.

And it shows the parsed data like this :

```
{
"id": "402089739910371",
"url": "http://maummeditationbenefits.org/blog/2013/06/19/maum-meditation-youth-camp/",
"type": "website",
"title": "Maum Meditation Youth Camp | Maum Meditation Benefits",
"image": [
    {"url": "http://maummeditationbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/maum-meditation-benefits-logo.png",
    "width": 397,
    "height": 51},
    {"url": "http://maummeditationbenefits.org/wp-content/themes/opinions/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fmaummeditationbenefits.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F07%2Funiv_camp.jpg&q=90&w=208&h=110&zc=1"},
    {"url": "http://maummeditationbenefits.org/wp-content/themes/opinions/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fmaummeditationbenefits.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F07%2FIMG_1317_thumb.jpg&q=90&w=208&h=110&zc=1"},
    {"url": "http://maummeditationbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/banner-Chambooks.png"},
    {"url": "http://cache.addthis.com/cachefly/static/btn/v2/lg-share-en.gif"}
    ],
"description": "Here at the Maum Meditation Youth Camp, well there is human mind which has been accumulated throughout the childrens lives, so Maum Meditation changes that mind into the Universe mind. This camp enables kids to throw away that human mind. So, as they throw away their mind by following this method, t…",
"updated_time": "2013-07-30T09:48:06+0000",
"created_time": "2013-06-19T18:19:41+0000",
"is_scraped": true
}
```

But inside the image array, there is no featured image URL.

This situation is the same in all posts.

Now SEO plugin and Facebook Open Graph Meta For WordPress plugin are disabled.

But when I enabled those plugin, the result was same.

So only Jetpack Open Graph Tags is working now :

```
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Maum Meditation Youth Camp" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://maummeditationbenefits.org/blog/2013/06/19/maum-meditation-youth-camp/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Here at the Maum Meditation Youth Camp, well there is human mind which has been accumulated throughout the childrens lives, so Maum Meditation changes that mind into the Universe mind. This camp en..." />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Maum Meditation Benefits" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://maummeditationbenefits.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/youth_camp.jpg" />
```

But still Facebook open graph cannot pull the value of "og:image".

It means when I try to share the post, it only shows other images not featured.

Can anyone tell me what to do?